# Having an issue with a query

Tags: codeigniter

I'm new to CodeIgniter and having an issue with a query.

I want to view a customer that's in my database, so I'm selecting a row based on ID.

Here is my model:

```
public function view($id)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('company');
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get('company');
    return $query->result();
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
public function view($id)
{
    $this->load->model('Company_model');
    $data = $this->Company_model->view($id);
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('company/view', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

and here is the view:

```
<?php echo $data('id'); ?>
```

viewing it, I get:

> Message: Undefined variable: id

Any help would be appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view function give like

```
$data['data'] = $this->Company_model->view($id);
```

First print the $data and see how the id will be retrived And in your view display the data as

```
<?php echo $data['id']; ?>
```

It should be "[]" not "()" and I think you are getting all the array of records so you need to use a loop for the data to retrieve

Comment: i tried that but im getting error: Undefined index: id still. does my model look correct?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's because of what you have in the view. `$data` is not a function but you are treating it as such. When information is passed from the the controller to the view, it is passed as an associative array which is square bracket notation:

```
$data['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that when you use

> return $query->result();

You are actually sending back an object and not an array, this is in addition to @ChritopherW answer.

Comment: if i am trying to query a row, wouldnt i want this instead of an array?

Comment: There is no problem working with an object instead of an array, but you need to call the object element correctly, so in your view whenever you need any one of the element of the row you should use
**$data->elementName**
For example for the id element of the row:
**$data->id**

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is that the view() method in your model is actually returning an object.

Try this =]

Model:

```
public function view($id)
{
    /** $this->db->select(); for a 'SELECT *' you can omit this function call **/

    $query = $this->db->get_where('company', array('id' => $id), 1);

    return $query->row(); /* This returns the result object limited to the first row */
}
```

Controller:

```
public function view($id)
{
    $this->load->model('Company_model');

/** OK, two things are going on the next line of code, on the right side, we are selecting the 'id' parameter of the object returned by the view() method in the model
and we are applying that information to the $data[id] array, where the id hash in the array will become a public variable from the view's POV
**/
    $data[id] = $this->Company_model->view($id)->id;
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('company/view', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

View:

```
<!-- HTML CODE HERE -->
<?php

/* Remember the $data[id] in the controller? */
echo $id; 

?>
```